# mysql slow on updates for a well optimized query

Tags: php, mysql

i am facing an issue with update state , which takes up to 4s on very small queries .

```
Count: 1  Time=3.87s (3s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), ***[***]@localhost
  UPDATE p_villages v SET v.resources='1 3273182 240000000 1500 245000 25,2 3273236 240000000 1500 245000 25,3 3273280 240000000 1500 245000 25,4 166973998 280000000 1500 3675000 325', v.cp='2941.8712 1867', v.crop_consumption=v.crop_consumption+1, v.troops_num='-1:11 0,12 0,13 0,14 9628,15 0,16 0,17 0,18 0,19 0,20 0,99 0', v.last_update_date=NOW() WHERE v.id='20899'



Count: 1  Time=2.97s (2s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), ***[***]@localhost
  UPDATE p_villages v
  SET
  v.update_key='38c47',
  v.resources='1 827064241 840000000 1500 800 0,2 814159650 840000000 1500 800 0,3 801255060 840000000 1500 800 0,4 839968830 840000000 1500 1200 0',
  v.cp='27.304202777778 1106',
  v.last_update_date=NOW()
  WHERE
  v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='22290'
```

example of query is :

```
db::query("UPDATE p_villages v SET v.resources=:res, v.cp=:cp, v.crop_consumption=v.crop_consumption+$troops_crop_consumption, v.troops_num=:tnum, v.last_update_date=NOW() WHERE v.id=:id", array(
            'res' => $this->_getResourcesString($resultArr['resources']),
            'cp' => $resultArr['cp']['cpValue'] . " " . $resultArr['cp']['cpRate'],
            'tnum' => $troopTrainingStr,
            'id' => intval($taskRow['village_id'])
        ));
```

id is indexed

updates : //

this is the result of explain

Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

```
explain UPDATE p_villages v
  SET
  v.update_key='38c47',
  v.resources='1 827064241 840000000 1500 800 0,2 814159650 840000000 1500 800 0,3 801255060 840000000 1500 800 0,4 839968830 840000000 1500 1200 0',
  v.cp='27.304202777778 1106',
  v.last_update_date=NOW()
  WHERE
  v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='1'



1   UPDATE  v   
    NULL
    range   PRIMARY,NewIndex2,NewIndex6 PRIMARY 4   const   1   100.00  Using where
```

this is much more simple query , that takes 2.39s ..

```
Count: 5  Time=2.39s (11s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), ***[***]@localhost
  UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.qlocked=1, qlocked_date=NOW() WHERE gs.qlocked=0
```

as requested this is the result of query SHOW CREATE TABLE p_villages

```
p_villages  CREATE TABLE `p_villages` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rel_x` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rel_y` smallint(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_maps_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rand_num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_num` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tribe_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alliance_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_name` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alliance_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_capital` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_special_village` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_oasis` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `people_count` int(11) DEFAULT 2,
  `crop_consumption` bigint(16) DEFAULT 2,
  `time_consume_percent` float DEFAULT 100,
  `offer_merchants_count` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `resources` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buildings` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_training` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_num` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_out_num` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_intrap_num` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_out_intrap_num` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `troops_trapped_num` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `allegiance_percent` int(11) DEFAULT 100,
  `child_villages_id` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_oases_id` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_key` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `NewIndex2` (`player_id`),
  KEY `NewIndex3` (`is_special_village`),
  KEY `NewIndex4` (`is_oasis`),
  KEY `NewIndex5` (`people_count`),
  KEY `NewIndex1` (`village_name`),
  KEY `NewIndex6` (`player_id`,`is_oasis`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Comment: Is PHP related? Does the query execute the same in DB directly? What does `explain` show?

Comment: Did you create indexes for `id` and `player_id` or the combination of those two?

Comment: If your query is well optimized, have you checked server configuration? You may need to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 50% of physical ram and then restart mysql service

Comment: hello guys. , i have added explain results to thread , and yes everything is indexed

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size is already more than 50% :(

Comment: then you probably need more RAM

Comment: my ram is very high ( 130g ) and not using 2% of it

Comment: We can better assist you if you will post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE p_villages;  and  B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'p_villages';  We will then have current information about each column and all your indexes for this one table.

Comment: @Zeyad Thanks for the SHOW CREATE TABLE p_villages; report. Your Update query that includes WHERE v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='1' would have better performance if you did NOT quote the search values used for lookup. When the variables are INTeger type, quoting the search values only SLOWS down the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  If not then that can be a big problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE p_villages`

You say `id` is indexed but is it the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, unique.  Hence only one row is involved, and the query *should* be very fast (a few *milliseconds*).

Are other queries running at the same time?  They could be blocking access to the one row.

Adding RAM, plus increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` won't help much; "3 seconds" is some other problem.  What value do you have for that setting?

If `id` is unique, why do you also test `player_id` in `WHERE v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='1'`  (There is no problem here, just a puzzle.)

If `id` is unique, the one of these will succeed, one will fail:

```
v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='22290'
v.id='1084' AND v.player_id='1'
```

"everything is indexed" -- The query sets 4 columns; this implies that 4 indexes need to be updated.  (Still, this would only take a few extra milliseconds.)

Comment: hello , thanks for your kind response . yes it is InnoDB, i updated the post with the results of requested query . and yes many requests are running at same time as it is a website that works on page load ,we ask for for 2 player_ids as one is the attacker and other is defender

Comment: Might some other thread be running a lengthy transaction (BEGIN...COMMIT)?

Comment: i do not use transactions in query , it is simple queries .. , i guess the issue is that when try to do query it locks whole table not only the row being used , is there a way to make it only locks the row not the whole table ?

Comment: InnoDB only locks the relevant rows; MyISAM locks the whole table.  I'm stumped.